# Simple examples of equivariant cobordism

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, cobordism

Let $Y$ be an oriented 3-manifold with a free action by a finite group $G$. If I understand correctly, there exists a multiple of $NY$ of $Y$ and an oriented manifold $X$ such that $\partial X = NY$ and $G$ extends to a free action on $X$. (That is, the equivariant oriented cobordism group is finite. Here, I believe $NY$ should be interpreted as $N$ disjoint copies of $Y$ - note that $N$ is nonzero.) I am trying to understand some very simple examples of this. For instance, if $Y = S^3$ and $G$ is a cyclic group (so that the quotient is a lens space), what is the manifold $X$?

EDIT: For a concrete mention of this claim, see the bottom of the first page of [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/aps002.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/aps002.pdf)

I realize that the claim is from equivariant bordism theory (as mentioned in one of the comments) but I am not very familiar with this, so I just gave the place where I first saw it.

Comment: I'm confused -- applying your claim to the trivial group $G$, it would imply that the ordinary oriented cobordism group is finite, which is of course false.

Comment: @AndyPutman I think this bordism theory is equivalent to the bordism theory of oriented manifolds with a principal $G$-bundle (depending on whether $G$ must act by orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms -- if not, this gets more complicated). Since $G$ is finite, this contains infinite-order elements when $n\equiv 0\bmod 4$, and is torsion otherwise (e.g. by an Atiyah-Hirzebruch argument). So the second part of the question, asking about $n = 3$, is still valid.

Comment: @AndyPutman My apologies - I think indeed I only care about $n = 3$. The question has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Following @ArunDebray's comment, the AHSS shows that the relevant bordism group is $\Omega_3(BG)\cong H_3(BG;\mathbb{Z})$, which is annihilated by $|G|$, so we may take $N=|G|$. In fact, $G\times Y$ (where $G$ acts on $Y$) is equivariantly cobordant to $G\times Y$ (where $G$ acts on $G$). Is there a geometic way to see this?

Answer (score 2):

For the concrete case of the cyclic group $C_p$ acting linearly on $S^3$, there's a very explicit construction. Call $\omega = e^{2\pi i/p}$. Fix an integer $q$ coprime with $p$, and let us look at the action $\lambda_q$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ generated by the diagonal matrix with entries $\omega, \omega^q$. $\lambda_q$ restricts to an action (which I will still call $\lambda_q$) on $S^3$ (as the unit sphere in $\mathbb C^2$ whose quotient is $L(p,q)$.

Take $M = V(x_0^p + \dots + x_3^p)$, the Fermat hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{CP}^3$. On $\mathbb{CP}^3$ we define two actions $\psi$ and $\phi$ of $C_p$. Calling $g$ the generator of $C_p$, the two actions are given by:
$\phi_g(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3) = (\omega x_0 : \omega^{-q}x_1 : x_2 : x_3)$, and $\psi_g(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3) = (x_0 : x_1 : \omega x_2 : x_3)$.
I claim that:

- Both actions preserve $M$.
- The fixed point set of the action $\phi$ on $M$ is the set of points $(0:0:1:\omega^a)$ as $a$ varies, and the action is semi-free (i.e. there are no new fixed points appearing when you take powers of $g$).
- $\psi_g$ cyclically permutes the fixed points of $\phi_g$ on $M$.
- $\phi_g$ and $\psi_g$ commute.
- The linearised action of $\phi_g$ on $M$ at $(0:0:1:1)$ is $\lambda_{-q}$.

I will not justify these points (the only one that maybe requires some care is the last one), and I will just take them for granted. Now take a small $\phi_g$-invariant ball $B$ in $M$ centred at $(0:0:1:1)$ and remove all its $\psi_g$-orbit in $M$, to get $M_0$. The action of $\phi$ on $M_0$ is free (because $\phi_{g^k}$ has the same fixed points as $\phi_g$ for each $0 < k< p$) and it extends the linear action $\lambda_q$ on $pS^3 = \sqcup_k \psi_{g^k} \partial B$. (Note that there is a $-q$ in an exponent of $\omega$ when defining $\phi$: this is because the boundary of $M_0$ is the boundary of $B$ with its orientation reversed.)